# Flex Layout: can width be 100% of the *visible* area of a larger container

Tags: apache-flex, layout

I've got the following situation, where I have an outer Vbox that is set at a fixed width, and then inside it there is a header made from an HBox and a content area (Canvas) that is much wider than the enclosing VBox (and therefore requires scrollbars on the outer VBox to see it all).

I would like to set the width of the header to fill the entire width of the outer container, but only the visible part, and to remain fixed so that when I scroll to view the content, the header doesn't move.

Can anyone tell me how I can acomplish this please

```
    ______________________________
   |  _________________________   |       
   | |_________________________|  |
   |                     |     
   |  ____________________________|_ _ _ _ _ 
   | |                            |         |
   | |                            |         |
   | |                            |         |
   | |                            |         |
   |  ---------------------------------------
   |                              |
   |______________________________|
   |<|__________________________|>|
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a VBox with 1) a header at the top, and 2) a VBox underneath the header with your canvas inside that. The other answer will also work. And those graphics help a lot, good man.

Answer (score 1):

[Use Group as a wrapper:](http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/hgroup-vgroup-layout-oversiz/)

```
<Child1/>

<s:Group width="100%">
    <Child2 left="0" right="0'/>
</s:Group>

<Child3/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's Flex 4 and I'm on Flex 3 (my fault, another thing I didn't mention in my previous post).

Comment: One solution I have come up with earlier is, on initialization, get the width of the main container and set the header's width to that. That looks fine, until you start scrolling of course.

Comment: Ooh, I've got an even better solution now; I set the width of the header to the width of the main container. Then, I capture the scroll event, and resize it to the width of the container + the scroll position, so scrolling backwards and forwards resizes the header dynamically.

Comment: too smart :) just split scrollable and fixed part, that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the header fixed above VBox, just not add it in. Place it above (create wrapper Canvas for VBox and header). Instead of header place UIComponent with corresponding height to take place of header.

BTW, +1 for patience with pseudographics :)

Comment: Thanks both of you for you answers, glad the graphics helped :) I'm trying those suggestions out now but one thing I forgot to mention is that I don't have control of the outer box, only the inside. The outer box is a system-wide placeholder for the application's main page content. Not sure if that changes anything. Anyway, I'll see how I get on, thanks!